# How can I understand file downloading is finished programatically?

Tags: python, network-programming, packet-sniffers

I want to extract file from pcap file programatically. For example, when I tried to extract PE file, I am searching MZ header in data. But I couldn't understand when whole file will be received. How can I solve this? Second problem is what will happen when a packet duplicated?

Comment: This problem is hard and not for the inexperienced. There's no easy way to solve it generically as it depends on the protocol being used to send the file. Without "deep packet inspection" (decoding IP, TCP, and any higher layers' headers), you have little hope of succeeding. (And once you have done the TCP decoding, you will then have a hope of handling duplicate packets since the TCP algorithm defines that.) Best to look for software that already does this. Bro, for example, has some support for extracting files -- see bro.org. Maybe other IDS systems too.

Comment: I am using python module scapy. According to the my basic algorithm first check file type if it is `application/x-dosexec` get content length then collect data. Is it right? And what is the TCP algorithm for handling duplicated packets?